# Why does my open ResultSet automatically close after alter session

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

We have code that opens a `ResultSet` against a view in the Oracle root container, `cdb$root`.  While the code iterates the rows, there is a use case where we need to perform a specific function call but this call must be made within the context of a specific plugable database, in our case `ORCLDPB1`.  Effectively the code looks like the following:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
  LOGGER.info("ResultSet Closed (Top Of Loop): {}", resultSet.isClosed());
  if (someSpecialUseCaseIsTrue) {
    try (Statement s = connection.createStatement()) {
      LOGGER.info("ResultSet Closed (Creating new statement): {}", resultSet.isClosed());
      try {
        s.executeUpdate("ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=ORCLPDB1");
        LOGGER.info("ResultSet Closed (after alter session): {}", resultSet.isClosed());
        // perform some PDB specific operation
      }
      finally {
        s.executeUpdate("ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=cdb$root");
        LOGGER.info("ResultSet Closed (after alter back to root): {}", resultSet.isClosed());
      }
    }     
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
ResultSet Closed (Top Of Loop): false
ResultSet Closed (Creating new statement): false
ResultSet Closed (after alter session): true
ResultSet Closed (after alter back to root): true
```

Then when the while checks `resultSet.next()` on the second iteration this yields

```
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset: next
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.ensureOpen(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:428)
```

Through debugging, I've determined that the outer `ResultSet` remains open until the `ALTER SESSION` is executed and immediately afterward making call to `isClosed()` returns that the outer result-set is  no longer open.

Is this behavior due to performing another operation while an existing `ResultSet` is open or is this because of the actual statement being executed, namely `ALTER SESSION`?  If the latter, why does this force a `ResultSet` to be invalidated?

Comment: In Oracle, DDL statements perform a commit after they're executed. I don't know exactly if this would close an open result set, but it sure looks that way, doesn't it?

Comment: Which version of jdbc driver do you use?

Comment: Oracle ojdbc.jar 21.1.0.0

Comment: `ALTER SESSION` commits the transaction, which by default closes cursors. Make sure your create the `Statement` object with `resultSetHoldability = ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT`, e.g. by specifying it on the `conn.prepareStatement(String sql, int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency, int resultSetHoldability)` call.

Comment: @Andreas I checked the outer statement creation code and it already does that, `prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT)`

Comment: I've also confirmed that the statement object isn't closed, its only the result-set that gets closed.

Comment: `alter system` and `alter session` are not DDL commands and never commit current transaction: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Types-of-SQL-Statements.html#GUID-B8AEC1B3-D1E8-4567-9EFB-8F3410CA70A4

Comment: It's really interesting question and I'll investigate it tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

From the [Oracle "Administering a CDB with SQL*Plus" documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_admin.htm#ADMIN13616):

> ### 40.2.3 Switching to a Container Using the ALTER SESSION Statement
>
> ...
>
> The following are considerations for using the `ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER` statement:
>
> - ...
> - If you open a cursor and use `ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER` to switch to different container, then you cannot fetch data from that cursor until you switch back to the container in which the cursor was opened.

Comment: Hi @MT0, if you look at the code provided, I do switch back to the previous container.

Comment: @Naros Yes, but you've cut so much code from the example that I have no idea where you are making the `isClosed()` call that you discuss in the text. If you make it between the two `ALTER SESSION` statements then it may appear to be closed.

Comment: I've updated the original post with more detail to give you a better idea of what I'm observing with the text output from the logs as well as the exception thrown.

Comment: @Naros I am assuming that if you remove the calls to `isClosed()` then it still fails?

Comment: Yes, the LOGGER calls were added after the `next()` call in the second iteration threw the provided exception as a means to try and identify where the result set could have been being invalidated.

Comment: Just checking that you have not forced the issue. If, for example, ResultSet were to maintain an internal state of whether it is closed or not and by forcing it to check when in a different container then a flag was set and that internal state would be used rather than polling the database once the container was swapped back.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I've checked simple scenario in SQL*Plus - it works fine:

```sql
SQL> alter session set container=pdb1;

Session altered.

SQL> create table test as select 1 a from dual;

Table created.

SQL> var c refcursor;
SQL> exec open :c for select * from test;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> alter session set container=cdb$root;

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set container=pdb1;

Session altered.

SQL> print c

         A
----------
         1
```

As you can see I opened cursor in PDB1, switched to CDB$ROOT, then returned to PDB1 and successfully fetched from cursor.

So what exactly are you doing in `// perform some PDB specific operation`?
Are there any transactions?

Comment: So the outer cursor is against `V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS` and the PDB operation is to make a call to `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` but we have to do this within the context of the PDB where the table exists for which we want the DDL for.